# Git rev-list is it possible to output in in reverse order using GIT command only not bash?

Tags: windows, git, git-rev-list

trying to get only one result from selected commits returns the same output regardless of
output order.

**TOTAL LIST LENGTH 130 COMMITS**

**The result is the same, but the list is different**

showing reduced results :

```
$ git rev-list  --reverse origin/a..origin/b -10
c4fe26e8ebc8a2ceb0129a6f7318b08d18126baa
fd302babdae3338a2d780b529ec8499867d1c330
d24b219372ff87ada2c196857f47f7a9c61f1fad
1eaf20b79e69ae4d729a2679bdc40f6b2d22958f
6a76950fd9eee705ed813aec0c44ac58ff3a030c
058e793dbcd507861880b21aacf2dd07d2b079ff
f8bb9225c4101bf1340e35abd609e526d2bde2c1
a01e72042582337ff74f64caa0e5a25ceeba6c8d
bc88772e4cb3be926639da6d71a57aaef507cbf0
315f11516b98454cb8732ac57b9cc53dff9460b5


$ git rev-list  origin/a..origin/b -10
315f11516b98454cb8732ac57b9cc53dff9460b5
bc88772e4cb3be926639da6d71a57aaef507cbf0
a01e72042582337ff74f64caa0e5a25ceeba6c8d
f8bb9225c4101bf1340e35abd609e526d2bde2c1
058e793dbcd507861880b21aacf2dd07d2b079ff
6a76950fd9eee705ed813aec0c44ac58ff3a030c
1eaf20b79e69ae4d729a2679bdc40f6b2d22958f
d24b219372ff87ada2c196857f47f7a9c61f1fad
fd302babdae3338a2d780b529ec8499867d1c330
c4fe26e8ebc8a2ceb0129a6f7318b08d18126baa

$ git rev-list --max-count=1  origin/a..origin/b
315f11516b98454cb8732ac57b9cc53dff9460b5


$ git rev-list --reverse --max-count=1 origin/a..origin/b
315f11516b98454cb8732ac57b9cc53dff9460b5
```

> List commits that are reachable by following the parent links from the
> given commit(s), but exclude commits that are reachable from the
> one(s) given with a ^ in front of them. The output is given in reverse
> chronological order by default.

the command i use

```
git rev-list --max-count=1 $TARGET_BRANCH..$BASE_BRANCH
```

from [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#_options)

> Note that these are applied before commit ordering and formatting
> options, such as --reverse.
>
> -
> -n 
> --max-count= Limit the number of commits to output.

using the following git version

**git version 2.39.0.windows.1**

Comment: You're posting pictures of text and asking how to reverse the order of a single-item list. These are not good signs in a technical forum.

Comment: removed images and added commits list length

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the goalposts keep moving.

Answer (score 1):

The cited section from the documentation explains that the meaning of

```
git rev-list --max-count=1 --reverse $TARGET_BRANCH..$BASE_BRANCH
```

is:

1. Collect commits in the range `$TARGET_BRANCH..$BASE_BRANCH` in the usual way.
2. Truncate the collect list after the first entry (`--max-count=1`).
3. List the remaining commit in reverse order (`--reverse`).

Of course, if the list has only one entry, the printed result looks the same regardless if printed forward or in reverse.

Comment: list is 130 commits long , is this mean this is not possible to get the result i need ?

Comment: Your question only asks for an explanation of the observed behavior, but not for a solution of a specific problem.

Comment: changed the question to better description .

Comment: Don't post images of text. Post the text.

Answer (score 1):

As the docs you link say, `git rev-list`'s `--max-count` is applied very early, *before* `--reverse`.

To get the effect you're asking for, use existing tools. `git rev-list origin/a..origin/b | tail -1` to get the last entry.

Comment: my mistake i must use git command only tail is bash command - updated the question

Comment: @galsi that command is part of every git install.

Comment: tail is not a git command it is derived from Bash. i am trying to create a command with git only command - as i see from the answers this is not possible.